# europemap using raphael.js

Tags: raphael

I need to create a  European map with raphael.js.When mouse over on it,it should display the country name.I don know whether raphael itself form a MAP with the points else do we have to have a map.I really dont  have any idea,Please help me on this.I tried looking at the site http://playground.mobily.pl/tutorials/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael/demo.html,it says something like SVG.Where should I declare that in javascript.

Can anyone help me with this how can i start up or some clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

You do need the contour of every country in SVG format and all of those should be in the same coordinate system, of course.

If you check the source of the page you refer to, it references a [javascript file](http://playground.mobily.pl/assets/demo/tutorials/rmap/js/paths.js) that contains those paths.